# According to selected value from spinner, appropriate result should be displayed

Tags: android

```
public class ProductList extends Activity
{
    String m_brandName, m_modelName, m_categoryName;
    ListView mListView;
    private static ProductList actAppChartCatList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);

        m_brandName = getIntent().getStringExtra("Brand_Name");
        m_modelName = getIntent().getStringExtra("Model_Name");
        m_categoryName = getIntent().getStringExtra("Category_Name");

        actAppChartCatList = this;

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_list);

        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.showProductLists);
    }
    public static ProductList getInstance()
    {
        return actAppChartCatList;
    }
}
```

There is one Activity in my app named "ApplicationChart" consist of 3 spinners. One for Vehicle Brand, Second for Vehicle Model, and third for Category like Horns, lights etc. I have populated all the records in respective spinners. On Click of Submit Button from first activity, I just want to display 'Product List According to Category' on next Activity named "Product List". And all these I want to achieve using web service. Please guide me.

Comment: show us the code so far

Comment: I have posted Second Activity. Just tell me what to add more to fulfill the requirement. Do I need to use asynctask?

Answer (score 0):

OnClick Of Submit Button please read all value from spinner.
Suppose you have 3 spinners namely
spinner1,spinner2,spinner3 
Then on OnClick of submit get value of three spinner

```
String text1 = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
String text2 = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();
String text3 = spinner3.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Pass it to next activity through intent bundle

```
Intent nextActivity=new Intent(this,NextActivity.class);
nextActivity.putExtra("key1",text1);
```

and so on.

Then in NextActivity read all these value and do your actions

Comment: Fair enough. Do I need to use asynctask for performing further actions?

Comment: If you need to consume web service you got to use asynctask as its a network call you cannot use it from main UI thread . You will get NetWorkOnMainThreadException. SO you can go with asyncTask